# How can I output to STDERR with Swift?

Tags: macos, swift

I'm trying to make a command line tool for OS X with Xcode 6 and the new Swift language. How can I send output to stderr? Is this done with println?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For Swift 4.x:

```
import Darwin
fputs("hello from libc\n", stderr)
```

Comment: This requires a trailing `\n` to flush, maybe not too optimal.

Comment: @user187676 You can configure stderr to be non buffering then it will flush immediately but that is rather sub-optimal for performance. Also stderr will flush without a `\n`, once the buffer is full. And you you want to flush immediately but not have a line break, you can use `fflush()` to do so.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a Swift 3 snippet modified from https://gist.github.com/algal/0a9aa5a4115d86d5cc1de7ea6d06bd91.

```
import Foundation

var standardError = FileHandle.standardError

extension FileHandle: TextOutputStream {
  public func write(_ string: String) {
    let data = Data(string.utf8)
    self.write(data)
  }
}

print("I am printed to stderr", to: &standardError)
```

Comment: This is a great Swifty solution! I also added a new global `errorPrint` method (named like the `debugPrint` method), to simplify this :)

Comment: This is definitely the best solution because it works for any file handle.

Answer (score 23):

May be a better way to do it, but you can use `NSFileHandle`:

```
import Foundation

// Create a file handle to work with
let stderr = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardError()

// Build up a string; whatever you want
let stuff = "something"
let something = "I'm a string with \(stuff) in it\n"

// Write it
stderr.writeData(something.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there should be an easier way to do it. Both Python and C have easier ways to do it. I find it surprising that Swift wouldn't also. I'll mark this as the correct answer if nothing better comes up.

Comment: It doesn't shock me. There's no Cocoa way to do it, either, other than this. There's just a C way (stdout), which isn't Cocoa. Apple has definitely focused Swift on "app" problems, not command line problems. (I do a lot of work on the command line too...)

Comment: Does this work for you? println("foo", STDERR_FILENO)

Comment: @GeneDeLisa That prints out `(foo, 2)`.

Answer (score 15):

Not really a separate answer, but building on top of Rob Napier's answer, we can create a stderr like object so that there is not much to change when Apple comes around to providing stderr as an `OutputStreamType`:

```
import Foundation

class StandardErrorOutputStream: OutputStreamType {
  func write(string: String) {
    let stderr = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardError()
    stderr.writeData(string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
  }
}

var mx_stderr = StandardErrorOutputStream()

println("on-stdout")
println("on-stderr", &mx_stderr)
```

EDIT: As of 8/26/2015, Xcode 7 Beta 6, you need the `toStream:` parameter name, like so:

```
println("on-stderr", toStream:&mx_stderr)
```

Comment: Or just `func write(string: String) { fputs(string, stderr) }` :)

Comment: I was quite surprised to find that Swift's `print` uses C's `stdio` underneath - I wrote a function that uses `funopen` to redirect "normal" `stdout`, and it intercepts `print()` too.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4, similar to Ryan's solution but instead of extending the FileHandle, created a new struct which also lets you create a StdErr specific class and avoids the global.

```
struct StandardErrorOutputStream: TextOutputStream {
    let stderr = FileHandle.standardError

    func write(_ string: String) {
        guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
            fatalError() // encoding failure: handle as you wish
        }
        stderr.write(data)
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
do { 
    try somethingThatMightFail() 
} catch let error {
    var errStream = StandardErrorOutputStream()
    print("\(error)", to: &errStream)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Xcode 13.2+ and Swift 5.5+

Model:

```
class StandardError: TextOutputStream {
  func write(_ string: String) {
    try! FileHandle.standardError.write(contentsOf: Data(string.utf8))
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var standardError = StandardError()
print("Error!", to: &standardError)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are three different methods of increasing complexity:

Compliments of Erica Sadun at http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/09/swift-2-0-how-to-print/:

```
public struct StderrOutputStream: OutputStreamType {
    public mutating func write(string: String) {
        fputs(string, stderr)
    }
}

public var errStream = StderrOutputStream()

debugPrint("Hello", toStream: &errStream) // prints with new line
```

For a slightly different method using NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardError, see: http://crunchybagel.com/building-command-line-tools-with-swift/ in the section titled: **Writing to stdout / stderr**, but this method does not use Swift's print library function.

And for a really crazy ride, check out the method offered by rosettacode.org using NSOutputStream at https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Standard_error#Swift:

```
let out = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: "/dev/stderr", append: true)
let err = "Goodbye, World!".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
out?.open()
let success = out?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(err!.bytes), maxLength: err!.length)
out?.close()

if let bytes = success {
    print("\nWrote \(bytes) bytes")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the pile of answers:

```
func printStderr(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    let output = items
        .map { String(describing: $0) }
        .joined(separator: separator) + terminator
    
    FileHandle.standardError.write(output.data(using: .utf8)!)
}

// Usage
let answer = 42
printStderr("The answer is", answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

A condensed and modernized version of @RobNapiers suggested solution:

```
"A line of text"
    .data(using: .utf8)
    .map(FileHandle.standardError.write)
```

Comment: I appreciate the attractiveness of this, but it’s arguably an antipattern to have `map` with side effects. Very non-“functional”.